# Pyspark regexp_replace not pricing expected result

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Experts, i am trying to get rid of leading 0's and $ sign from the amount field in Pyspark and using regexp_replace for it, however i am not getting expected outcome-

```
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('abcd','$000000000000432.14')], ['s', 'd'])
>>> df.select(expr('regexp_replace((regexp_replace(d, "(\$)", "")), "(^0+)", "")').alias("d")).show()
+-------------------+
|                  d|
+-------------------+
|$000000000000432.14|
+-------------------+
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to nest the `regexp_replace` calls:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('abcd','$000000000000432.14')], ['s', 'd'])
df.select(F.regexp_replace(F.col("d"), "\$0*", "").alias("d")).show()
```

prints

```
+-------+
|      d|
+-------+
|432.14 |
+-------+
```